# Ruby .detect alternative

Tags: ruby, enumerate

I am looking for an alternative that would solve the following issue:

with `.detect` if I am looking for `stringvalue` and the value given is `132stringvalue`, it will still return true. I need an alternative that will be matching everything from the beginning of the string. Any suggestions aside from regex?

Comment: what you want to achieve not clear,give some examples. show your code.

Comment: Regular expressions are made specifically for this sort of thing. Why are you opposed to using them?

Comment: That would change a big portion of my code. I was hoping there is some similar funct that just does things from the start of the string. I guess I'll have to go with regex after all

Comment: Why would it change a big portion of your code? It sounds like your code isn't factored correctly. If you'd show examples of your code we could help fix that.

Comment: All the answers are given with the blind guesses, and you are responsible for this. Never post such in-completed questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[1] pry(main)> %w[foo 456foo bar 123bar].detect {|e| e.to_i > 0}
=> "456foo"
[2] pry(main)> %w[foo 456foo bar 123bar].detect {|e| e.start_with?('123')}                   
=> "123bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#[]` (see [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)):

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > "123stringvalue"["stringvalue"]
 => "stringvalue" 
1.9.3p194 :002 > "123stringvalue"["blah"]
 => nil
```

It returns the substring if present, `nil` otherwise.